# How to reduce cycles spent on /_ah/warmup

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

My app is spending a lot of time (about 30% of all CPU) in `/_ah/warmup`. Sounds like my app is not managing instances well! My app has little spikes but nothing major.

Why is GAE constantly spinning up these new instances when there are already old instances lying around? In the screenshot below, one instance is 5 seconds old, and another is 5 minutes old.

How can I improve this and reduce costs?

[image: app engine instance graph]

[image: instances]

Answer (score 2):

Java is known to be heavy on the start up. There are a few things to you can do to help but not eliminate the issue:

[Article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1760505&seqNum=3)

[Load on startup.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#using_a_load-on-startup_servlet) If you don't mind the initial calls to your site taking a little longer perhaps only loading the servlets you need.

Having more idle instances would also help.

Comment: In addition to Ryan suggestions you need to check if you have some Java filter or servlet that are fires on startup and do job that's not required, I think you can map a custom "warmup" servlet simply by mapping it on the /_ah/warmup path!